# Content of HTML file has changed after copying files from one directory to another in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I've created the functionality for copying the HTML files from one directory to another using `File::copyDirectory($source, $destination);` in Laravel. But after copying the files the HTML content is getting changed.

For Ex:
**Files From Source Dir (/themes/myDir/):** 

  index.html
about.html

**Destingation Dir is (/apps/myNewDir/)**

Now, I am copying the file from 'themes/myDir/' dir to 'apps/myNewDir/' dir. For that, I've written below code

```
$theme_dir = __DIR__.'/../../../themes/myDir';
$apps_dir = __DIR__.'/../../../apps/myNewDir';
File::makeDirectory($apps_dir);
return File::copyDirectory($theme_dir, $apps_dir);
```

After copying the file from one to another the html content is getting changed. 
Let's take content `index.html` file from `themes/myDir` below which is **original**

```
 <div class="row">
  <div id="fh5co-board" data-columns class="ftb-gallery">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="animate-box">
          <a href="assets/images/img_6.jpg" class="image-popup fh5co-board-img" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, eos?"><img src="assets/images/img_6.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Bootstrap template"></a>
       </div>
       <!--<div class="fh5co-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiszcing elit. Explicabo, eos?</div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Now, **after copying** the file with above php/laravel code the html data is showing like below.

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="fh5co-board" data-columns="4" class="ftb-gallery">
   <div class="column size-1of4"><div class="column size-1of4">
      <div class="column size-1of4"><div class="column size-1of4">
       <div class="item">
        <div class="animate-box bounceIn animated">
          <a href="assets/images/img_6.jpg" class="image-popup fh5co-board-img" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, eos?" data-url="assets/images/img_6.jpg">
               <img src="assets/images/img_6.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Bootstrap template">  
           </a>
         </div>
        <!--<div class="fh5co-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, eos?</div>-->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

This is something weird happening with me but I am sure there is some problem in this case. Now, I am struggling with finding the cause of this issue. How can it be possible? How is data changed? Is it possible?  
You can see more in view source from below links:

[Original HTML Code](http://zestarsystems.com/Projects/Float-Builder/themes/aGiAo1_demo/index.html)

[Copied HTML Code](http://www.zestarsystems.com/Projects/Float-Builder/apps/swQpIJu8/index.html)

Note: Please ignore the top missed code (in copied code) `<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!--[if lt IE 7]>` which I've removed manually. Please target the code from `<div id="fh5co-board">` and so on, you'll get difference between both.

Only sometimes it happens.

Comment: try to clear the cache, on both installs. from terminal: php artisan clear:cache (first thing that comes to mind, Im drunk :P)

Comment: @OleHaugset So you mean it's possible that content can change.

Comment: I have had some strange experiences with laravel cache. All Im saying is, just try it. If it doesn't help, then Im sorry my comment didn't do any good. As long as you have the same file structure, you don't get any 404's in the web browser console log, etc. Then maybe. Im not sure tbh. As I said, drunk, and now on my mobile phone